Read XML doc , want to extract certain element value and concatenate it
Trying to read XML data which is nothing but response from an API endpoint.
In java trying like below, but not able to read the virtualfile tag properly. I want to see what the permission user is have on virtual file, what is the path of the folder.
Please guide me. I have java code below which I am using, able to get name value but i need to find what Folder name, permission and path user have access to.
Users have access to multiple folders and with diff permission and paths.
Hence want to show this data in multiple lines.
OUTGOING\276\Path-B
INCOMING\778\Path-A
Document doc = XmlUtil.getDocument(rawResponseObject);
NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("webUser");

for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList1.getLength(); itr++)   
{ 
  Map nodeMap = new HashMap();
  Node node = nodeList1.item(itr);  
  

  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)   
  {  
    log.debug("Element loop");
    Element eElement = (Element) node;
    if (null!=eElement.getElementsByTagName("name") && eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").length > 0)
    {
      log.debug("Name element value");     
      log.debug(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent() );
    }
    
     if (null!=eElement.getElementsByTagName("virtualFile") && eElement.getElementsByTagName("virtualFile").length > 0)
     {
       log.debug("virtualFile element value");     
       //log.debug(eElement.getElementsByTagName("virtualFile").item(0).getTextContent() );
       String value=eElement.getElementsByTagName("virtualFile").item(0).getTextContent();
       log.debug(value );
     }
  }

}

Sample XML ,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<webUsers class="com.linom">

<webUser>
    <forcePasswordChange>true</forcePasswordChange>
    
    <name>ZONE</name>
    <firstName>Mus</firstName>
    <organization>Mus</organization>
    <as2MDNSignatureAlgorithmFormatCode></as2MDNSignatureAlgorithmFormatCode>
    <ghttpsTwoFactorAuthTypeCode>G</ghttpsTwoFactorAuthTypeCode>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    
    <lastName>Musbah</lastName>
    <phone></phone>
    
    <webGroups>
        <webGroup>
            <name>ALL Users Group</name>
        </webGroup>
    </webGroups>
    <ipFilterEntries />
    <virtualFile>
        <folderPermissions>256</folderPermissions>
        <diskQuotaSize>100</diskQuotaSize>
        <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
        <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
        <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
        <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
        <description>This is the login directory</description>
        <type>D</type>
        <virtualFiles>
            <virtualFile>
                <folderPermissions>257</folderPermissions>
                <diskQuotaSize>0</diskQuotaSize>
                <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
                <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
                <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
                <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
                <path>B</path>
                <type>D</type>
                <alias>OUTGOING</alias>
                <virtualFiles />
            </virtualFile>
            <virtualFile>
                <folderPermissions>778</folderPermissions>
                <diskQuotaSize>0</diskQuotaSize>
                <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
                <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
                <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
                <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
                <path>A</path>
                <type>D</type>
                <alias>INCOMING</alias>
                <virtualFiles />
            </virtualFile>
        </virtualFiles>
    </virtualFile>
    <secureForms />
</webUser>
<webUser>
    <forcePasswordChange>true</forcePasswordChange>
    
    <name>ZONE1</name>
    <firstName>Mus</firstName>
    <organization>Mus</organization>
    <as2MDNSignatureAlgorithmFormatCode></as2MDNSignatureAlgorithmFormatCode>
    <ghttpsTwoFactorAuthTypeCode>G</ghttpsTwoFactorAuthTypeCode>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    
    <lastName>Musbah</lastName>
    <phone></phone>
    
    <webGroups>
        <webGroup>
            <name>ALL Users Group</name>
        </webGroup>
    </webGroups>
    <ipFilterEntries />
    <virtualFile>
        <folderPermissions>256</folderPermissions>
        <diskQuotaSize>100</diskQuotaSize>
        <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
        <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
        <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
        <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
        <description>This is the login directory</description>
        <type>D</type>
        <virtualFiles>
            <virtualFile>
                <folderPermissions>257</folderPermissions>
                <diskQuotaSize>0</diskQuotaSize>
                <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
                <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
                <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
                <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
                <path>B</path>
                <type>D</type>
                <alias>OUTGOING</alias>
                <virtualFiles />
            </virtualFile>
            <virtualFile>
                <folderPermissions>778</folderPermissions>
                <diskQuotaSize>0</diskQuotaSize>
                <diskQuotaOption>B</diskQuotaOption>
                <diskQuotaUnit>M</diskQuotaUnit>
                <applyToSubfolders>true</applyToSubfolders>
                <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
                <path>A</path>
                <type>D</type>
                <alias>INCOMING</alias>
                <virtualFiles />
            </virtualFile>
        </virtualFiles>
    </virtualFile>
    <secureForms />
</webUser>

I am able to get the element Name but how to read virtualfile like <alias>INCOMING</alias>, <filePermissions>0</filePermissions>
want to concatenate this.

Have you looked at the documentation of the Element class and the documentation of its superclass?  They should provide you with all of the tools you need.

Thanks . i was able to resolve by adding NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("virtualFile"); replaced webuser, and then added following , to get value of each element
if (null!=eElement.getElementsByTagName("alias") && eElement.getElementsByTagName("alias").length > 0)
{
//log.debug("alias element value ");
  value=eElement.getElementsByTagName("alias").item(0).getTextContent();
  customvalues.add(value);

} just concatenated next element and got the desired result
